# Unable to load tensorflow tflite model in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a TensorFlow model and convert it to TensorFlow lite using the below code:

```py
# Convert the model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# path to the SavedModel directory is TFLITE_PATH
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(TFLITE_PATH) 

tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model_1.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Attaching my [model_1.tflite](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sB4fPwzlyfPuDjxONv1qXlALCXCe5xih/view?usp=sharing) model in case you want to investigate.
I have tested it inside my python environment, where it is producing output using the below script:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

MODEL_PATH = "model_1.tflite"

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=MODEL_PATH)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
```

##### Print required input shape for the model

```py
print(input_shape)
[  1 320 320   3]
```

#### Providing input details to the interpreter

```py
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

##### Print the output that we get from the model

```py
print(output_data)

[[[0.01350823 0.02189949 0.9918406  0.9821147 ]
[0.33122188 0.11993879 0.9528857  0.90357083]
[0.04370229 0.13977486 0.5076436  0.9069242 ]
[0.36508453 0.00325416 0.63923967 0.1383895 ]
[0.12694997 0.01493323 0.4414968  0.14510964]
[0.21113579 0.00826943 0.5027399  0.13861066]
[0.28166008 0.9081802  0.57174915 1.0400366 ]
[0.38398495 0.9090722  0.6709249  1.0427872 ]
[0.561202   0.32376498 0.8054305  0.6049366 ]
[0.3257156  0.65075576 0.43758994 0.80955625]]]
```

But when I am going to load it inside Android studio it is giving me the error.

Note: **when I downloaded a pre-trained TensorFlow model from here(https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin) and called it, it is working fine but I am unable to load my customized trained model and it is giving me the below error:**

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(1137)] Unhandled exception:
Bad state: failed precondition
#0      checkState (package:quiver/check.dart:73:5)
#1      Tensor.setTo (package:tflite_flutter/src/tensor.dart:150:5)
#2      Interpreter.runForMultipleInputs (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:194:33)
#3      Classifier.predict (package:bewizor/tflite/classifier.dart:139:18)
#4      IsolateUtils.entryPoint (package:bewizor/tflite/tfutils/isolate_utils.dart:45:51)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Below is the comparison of the output that I ran using the Netron app.

[image]
**On the left-hand side, Netron view of working pre-trained model, whereas on the right-hand side, Netron view of a failed customized trained model**

Can you please help to understand what I am lacking here and what are the things that I can try out to resolve this?

Why pre-trained tflite model was working? and why not my current custom model?

Is the error related to my model or the way I am calling it inside android studio should be changed?

Things that I have tried out to resolve this?

Try to make a model in a way to take uint8 as an input.(Idea is to make this looks like the model that is working fine but I don't think it is making an impact on model working but yes it is helpful to reduce the size of my model) Used the below code for this.

```py
# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_PATH) # path to the SavedModel directory

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
num_calibration_steps = 100
def representative_dataset_gen():
  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
    input_shape = [1, 320, 320, 3]
    input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)

    # Get sample input data as a numpy array in a method of your choosing.
    yield [input_data]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
converter.experimental_new_converter = False
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()
tflite_model_name = 'model_2_uint_type.tflite'

if tf.__version__.startswith('1.'):
    open(tflite_model_name, "wb").write(quantized_tflite_model)
if tf.__version__.startswith('2.'):
    with open(tflite_model_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(quantized_tflite_model)
```

Also sharing .dart file code which we are using to call the model inside android studio

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:bewizor/tflite/recognition.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter_helper/tflite_flutter_helper.dart';

import 'stats.dart';

/// Classifier
class Classifier {
  /// Instance of Interpreter
  Interpreter _interpreter;

  /// Labels file loaded as list
  List<String> _labels;

  // static const String MODEL_FILE_NAME = "tfModels/detect.tflite";

  static const String MODEL_FILE_NAME = "tfModels/detect_new.tflite";
  static const String LABEL_FILE_NAME = "tfModels/label_map.pbtxt";

  /// Input size of image (height = width = 300)
  static const int INPUT_SIZE = 300;

  /// Result score threshold
  static const double THRESHOLD = 0.5;

  /// [ImageProcessor] used to pre-process the image
  ImageProcessor imageProcessor;

  /// Padding the image to transform into square
  int padSize;

  /// Shapes of output tensors
  List<List<int>> _outputShapes;

  /// Types of output tensors
  List<TfLiteType> _outputTypes;

  /// Number of results to show
  static const int NUM_RESULTS = 5;

  Classifier({
    Interpreter interpreter,
    List<String> labels,
  }) {
    loadModel(interpreter: interpreter);
    loadLabels(labels: labels);
  }

  /// Loads interpreter from asset
  void loadModel({Interpreter interpreter}) async {
    try {
      _interpreter = interpreter ??
          await Interpreter.fromAsset(
            MODEL_FILE_NAME,
            options: InterpreterOptions()..threads = 4,
          );

      var outputTensors = _interpreter.getOutputTensors();
      _outputShapes = [];
      _outputTypes = [];
      outputTensors.forEach((tensor) {
        _outputShapes.add(tensor.shape);
        _outputTypes.add(tensor.type);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error while creating interpreter: $e");
    }
  }

  /// Loads labels from assets
  void loadLabels({List<String> labels}) async {
    try {
      _labels =
          labels ?? await FileUtil.loadLabels("assets/" + LABEL_FILE_NAME);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error while loading labels: $e");
    }
  }

  /// Pre-process the image
  TensorImage getProcessedImage(TensorImage inputImage) {
    padSize = max(inputImage.height, inputImage.width);
    if (imageProcessor == null) {
      imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
          .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(padSize, padSize))
          .add(ResizeOp(INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
          .build();
    }
    inputImage = imageProcessor.process(inputImage);
    return inputImage;
  }

  /// Runs object detection on the input image
  Map<String, dynamic> predict(imageLib.Image image) {
    var predictStartTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    if (_interpreter == null) {
      print("Interpreter not initialized");
      return null;
    }

    var preProcessStart = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    // Create TensorImage from image
    TensorImage inputImage = TensorImage.fromImage(image);

    // Pre-process TensorImage
    inputImage = getProcessedImage(inputImage);

    var preProcessElapsedTime =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - preProcessStart;

    // // TensorBuffers for output tensors
    TensorBuffer outputLocations = TensorBufferFloat(_outputShapes[0]);
    TensorBuffer outputClasses = TensorBufferFloat(_outputShapes[1]);
    TensorBuffer outputScores = TensorBufferFloat(_outputShapes[2]);
    TensorBuffer numLocations = TensorBufferFloat(_outputShapes[3]);

    // Inputs object for runForMultipleInputs
    // Use [TensorImage.buffer] or [TensorBuffer.buffer] to pass by reference
    List<Object> inputs = [inputImage.buffer];

    // Outputs map
    Map<int, Object> outputs = {
      0: outputLocations.buffer,
      1: outputClasses.buffer,
      2: outputScores.buffer,
      3: numLocations.buffer,
    };

    var inferenceTimeStart = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    // run inference
    _interpreter.runForMultipleInputs(inputs, outputs);

    var inferenceTimeElapsed =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - inferenceTimeStart;

    // Maximum number of results to show
    int resultsCount = min(NUM_RESULTS, numLocations.getIntValue(0));

    // Using labelOffset = 1 as ??? at index 0
    int labelOffset = 1;

    // Using bounding box utils for easy conversion of tensorbuffer to List<Rect>
    List<Rect> locations = BoundingBoxUtils.convert(
      tensor: outputLocations,
      valueIndex: [1, 0, 3, 2],
      boundingBoxAxis: 2,
      boundingBoxType: BoundingBoxType.BOUNDARIES,
      coordinateType: CoordinateType.RATIO,
      height: INPUT_SIZE,
      width: INPUT_SIZE,
    );

    List<Recognition> recognitions = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultsCount; i++) {
      // Prediction score
      var score = outputScores.getDoubleValue(i);

      // Label string
      var labelIndex = outputClasses.getIntValue(i) + labelOffset;
      var label = _labels.elementAt(labelIndex);

      if (score > THRESHOLD) {
        // inverse of rect
        // [locations] corresponds to the image size 300 X 300
        // inverseTransformRect transforms it our [inputImage]
        Rect transformedRect = imageProcessor.inverseTransformRect(
            locations[i], image.height, image.width);

        recognitions.add(
          Recognition(i, label, score, transformedRect),
        );
      }
    }

    var predictElapsedTime =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - predictStartTime;

    return {
      "recognitions": recognitions,
      "stats": Stats(
          totalPredictTime: predictElapsedTime,
          inferenceTime: inferenceTimeElapsed,
          preProcessingTime: preProcessElapsedTime)
    };
  }

  /// Gets the interpreter instance
  Interpreter get interpreter => _interpreter;

  /// Gets the loaded labels
  List<String> get labels => _labels;
}
```

Comment: Did you go through the below thread where they mention a similar case: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22803

Comment: ```converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(TFLITE_PATH)```
```converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]```
```converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]```
```tflite_model = converter.convert() ```

Comment: Tried this also but didn't work

Comment: I am not familiar with Flutter. But I see that the working file expects uint for input...but your model expects floats. Have you made changes accordingly so the inputs are floats? Or else you have to save the model using post integer quantization https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yes I have already tried out using uint8 input and output but got the same error. Just for further info I have adding this to my question

Comment: I think you should also include the inference code so anyone that is familiar with Dart can  understand where is the mistake.

Comment: Hi thanks for puting the code. If you set the debugger in what line you get the error? Is it
_interpreter.runForMultipleInputs(inputs, outputs); OR other line after or before. I do not have knowledge of Dart but the code seems very similar to kotlin and Java. Can you give us the link to github to build and debug?

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible as it is for internal use. I can provide other details if required.

Comment: Set the debugger then and see what line creates the problem?